# How to blit an ever-varying int array at animation speed to the screen in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a Java app that depends on **MemoryImageSource** with **Image** to copy the contents of an int array of changing RGBA data to a window at animation speed (~20fps). I'm trying to port this app to Android. What would be the closest equivalent to this in Android's API? If it helps explain, i used **DIBSection**s in WIndows to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use android's [2D Graphics](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) library to draw an animated image. I think [making the RGBA data a string](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ColorDrawable.html), and then making it a color drawable, which is animated using an [animation drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#mutate%28%29).